# `Can't create handler...Looper.prepare()` in inherited Activity

Tags: java, android, handler, toast, looper

I have a Game `Activity` (Activity A) that works well with all the code. Then I create a new `Activity` (Activity B) for my new game mode, that `extends` Activity A. However, when encounter the Toast line, Activity B suddenly thrown an exception (Activity A works well showing the Toast):

`Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Activity B only overrides a load-level method, no any differrence!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
Handler innerHandler;

(new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();

                innerHandler = new Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                        Toast.make(...);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void dispatchMessage(Message message) {
                        handleMessage(message);
                    }
                };

                Message message = innerHandler.obtainMessage();
                innerHandler.dispatchMessage(message);
                Looper.loop();
            }
        })).start();
```

There may be an easier way to handle the problem. Please refer to [Android – Multithreading in a UI environment](http://www.aviyehuda.com/2010/12/android-multithreading-in-a-ui-environment/) documentation.

Comment: I struggled with the same problem yesterday. I am happy that helped (:

Comment: @OnuraySahin I know this answer is from a long time ago, but I found it very helpful. However, I am getting a warning at `innerHandler = new Handler()` that says `This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur` However, making it static means that I can't access the context for the Toast. Do you know a way around this?

Comment: @Deena I think this is a Lint warning. Please try to pass Callback while creating Handler. Like this: innerHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {...

Comment: @OnuraySahin I tried that, and I'm still getting the same warning.