# how to refer to a method, defined in a package being tested from a test

Tags: java, junit

For example a package being tested has a method:

```
package package.being.tested
....
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
....
public Int myMehod(String s){
 <do something>
}
```

How to call this method in tests?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you would call this method in a non-test class.

```
@Test
public void myMethodTest() {
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    Integer i = mainActivity.myMethod("A string");
}
```

Comment: actually it gives RuntimeException: "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Comment: I cannot help you for that. But perhaps will you be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732529/cant-create-handler-looper-prepare-in-inherited-activity